Should SMTP HELO name be the same as the MX record?
I can't seem to satisfy HELO checks on SPF records in all cases. I have an SPF record for my domain like this:
"v=spf1 mx -all"
The MX records in the zone are:
mx0.mydomain.org.uk.          3600 IN A         1xx.xx.xx.59
mx0.mydomain.org.uk.          3600 IN AAAA      2001:xxx:x:xxx::3b
mx1.mydomain.org.uk.          3600 IN A         2xx.xx.xxx.201
mx1.mydomain.org.uk.          3600 IN AAAA      2a03:xxx:xx:xxx::2 

The host name (and PTR) of the sending server is mail.mydomain.org.uk. Its IP is the same as mx0.mydomain.org.uk.  The HELO name is mydomain.org.uk.
I can get HELO to pass with the above SPF record:
SPF helo    header      Received-SPF: 

pass (mydomain.org.uk: 1xx.xx.xx.59 is authorized to use 'mydomain.org.uk' in 'helo' identity (mechanism 'mx' matched)) 

receiver=ts11-do.checktls.com; identity=helo; helo=mydomain.org.uk; client-ip=1xx.xx.xx.59

However, some checkers don't like this and say they can't find an A record for the sender mydomain.org.uk. But if I change the HELO to mx0.mydomain.org.uk I then get a fail because of "no applicable sender policy available":
SPF helo    header      Received-SPF: 

none (mx0.mydomain.org.uk: No applicable sender policy available) receiver=ts11-do.checktls.com; identity=helo; helo=mx0.mydomain.org.uk; client-ip=1xx.xx.xx.59

SPF helo    local       mx0.mydomain.org.uk: No applicable sender policy available

How can I satisfy both checks?

Please share the domain. All information that you are hiding is already well known to the entire world, and it will make it easier to understand the point and the issue.

We'll have to agree to disagree about that, I'm afraid. But if you could give me the name of a domain and the mail server hostname/helo setting it uses, that might help me answer the question! :-)

some checkers which "checkers"?

In general, no. HELO name must match PTR and A records (that's true independently for each relay sending mail outwards, if you have many), but MXes can be very different. You aren't required to have MX servers the same as outgoing relays. I don't quite understand that "no policy available" error, though. Maybe, it means "your current host is not mentioned by the policy", e.g. it's name or IP should be added into the SPF record?

@GregAskew mail-tester.com complains about missing A record, while checktls.com does not.

@NikitaKipriyanov That's the thing that also confuses me. I guess I could put ipv4/6 of the HELO into the SPF but that would just duplicate the IP address of the MX records.

HELO and MX are independent. You can have one set of server that receive mail for your domain, and you publish them using MX records; and other set of servers that don't receive anything but relay outbound mail on behalf of your domain, the requirements under the link above are for this second set. It's these servers whose HELO matters; you don't publish themselves as such, but they must appear in SPF and they must have DKIM keys that correspond to selectors that exist in your DNS. Sometimes you don't even control them, for example, if you outsource mail lists to some mass email service.

@NikitaKipriyanov OK thanks. But for me, the MX and the HELO are on the same machine. If I make HELO "mydomain.org.uk" it works with checktls.com but mail-tester.com says it can't find my A. If I make the HELO "mail.mydomain.org.uk" checktls.com says "no applicable record" but mail-tester.com says it's OK.
Perhaps there's no way of satisfying both, and one or other just has a bug (Google says DMARC is OK, so maybe that's enough ¯_(ツ)_/¯

have you tried with mxtoolbox?

@djdomi mxtoolbox's report is silent on the issue of HELO.

I still assume that this question is not business-related, and that is, in my humble opinion, the reason why it will be kept hidden.

SPF mostly ignores the HELO name and uses the MAIL FROM name instead,  but when MAIL FROM is empty it uses the HELO name.
Use option 2.

change the HELO to mx0.mydomain.org.uk

"none" is not a rejection.

"no applicable sender policy available":

Seeing mx0.mydomain.org.uk the other end has no reason to look at
mydomain.org.uk  it will instead look for an SPF record on  mx0.mydomain.org.uk.   You can fix that by adding an SPF record for mx0.mydomain.org.uk.
eg: "v=spf1 a -all".

That I think would work, but I'd rather not have the same host name for both receiving and sending mail, so instead I solved it by adding another TXT record for the the mail host as follows: mail            IN      TXT "v=spf1 a -all I'll mark yours as the solution though as it's close enough :-)

While I've accepted @jasen as having the answer, the HELO of the mail server would need to be the same as the MX record. This might be inconvenient in future if we needed to have sending and receiving on separate IP addresses.
So I in fact solved it like this:

Keep the sending server's name as mail.mydomain.com, but make this the same as the HELO name.

Have the domain's SPF record as follows (authorises the addresses of all MX records):


@      IN      TXT "v=spf1 mx -all"

Add a separate SPF record for the mail server's name (authorises the A record of mail.mydomain.com):

mail   IN      TXT "v=spf1 a -all"
Now the checking services I've tried say everything is OK.
